# Generating unique number

Tags: c++, c

I have three variables of `int32` data type in C++. I want to generate unique number for combination of three `int32` numbers in `C++`. For example I have `int iVal1`, `int iVal2`, and `int iVal3`. Is there any algorithm to do this?

In order to avoid confusion in question I will rephrase the question. Basically I want to generate a unique number with three integers because I want to store this number as a key in map to retrieve the data.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Completely unclear. How "unique" should it be? How should those numbers mix into the result? Should the result be reproduceable?

Comment: Do you need a random number generated from the three ints, as suggested by the title of your question? Or do you need a way to compute a single number from the three in a more or less secure way? Should it be unique in mathematical sense? And should it be an int again? If the last two conditions hold, then this is not possible.

Comment: Random numbers and unique numbers are different things. You don't really explain what you need.

Comment: The tile and question don't match.A random number and a unique number are both different.You can try hashing for your purpose but it wont be unique always.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a good hash function.

Comment: or hash two times with time(NULL)

Answer (score 1):

concatenate the numbers together for a number with 3 times as many bits as a int has (96 bits)

number 1: 0xDEADFACE; number 2: 0xF00BA4; number 3: 42

result: 0xDEADFACE00F00BA40000002A

---

Edit: example usage that returns composes the new number to a string

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* writes a, b, c into dst
** dst must have enough space for the result */
char *concat3(char *dst, unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c) {
    sprintf(dst, "%08x%08x%08x", a, b, c);
    return dst;
}

/* usage */
int main(void) {
    char n3[25]; /* 25 = 3*8 for each integer + 1 for terminating null */
    concat3(n3, 0xDEADFACE, 0xF00BA4, 42);
    printf("result is 0x%s\n", n3);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run

```
$ ./a.out
result is 0xdeadface00f00ba40000002a
```

Comment: C doesn't deal directly with 96 bits values, but you can make strings instead. See my edit

Comment: You'd need a `char[12]` (or more generally, a `char[3*sizeof(int)]`. You can just `memcpy` the three ints to `char[0]`, `char[4]` and `char[8]`.

Comment: Add 1 to the buffer length so that you have space for the null character.

Comment: @Alex: 32 is enough for concatenating 3 integers (1 char short for 4 integers), but I'll change the array to save memory.

Comment: thanks for the guidence, but we got output as a string instead of integer, we want integer as a unique number, if we use atoi function will it works?

Comment: @Ventaka: read up on the "pigeonhole principle". It's mathematically impossible. There are 4 billion integers, which means there are 64 trillion trillion different combinations of 3 integers. No matter how I number those combinations, one of them must have a number equal or higher than 64 trillion trillion - and therefore that number won't fit in a single int.

Answer (score 0):

For a computational method you could look here: [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Another method for generating a unqiue number from three other numbers is addition (works at least once).

```
int n = x1 + x2 + x3
```

Now `n` is a new unique number.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The question could be interpreted so that this answer is correct. @Downvoter: please explain..

Comment: `n` is neither unique nor random.  x1 = x2 = 0 and x3 = 3 and x1 = x2 = x3 = 1 produce the same result.

Comment: @gregor: if you map 3 integers into one, what ever you do with those 3 integers, n will be neither unique nor random.

Comment: @Turkmen: that statement is obviously false, if you take a look at pmg's answer.

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis: What?  Gregor's statement is obviously true.  3x32 bit numbers mapping to 1x32 bit number will always result in duplication because you can't enumerate every combination of 96 bits with only 32 bits.  pmg's solution will not produce unique results e.g. if your numbers are 1, 2, 3 and your random number is 56436, this will produce the same result as if your numbers are 1, 56436, 2 and your random number is 3.

Comment: I said, it works at least once. So why shouldn't it be unique? If I have three numbers (> 0), and add them together, this will give me another number, which is not one of the other numbers.

Comment: You could also say that you can't do something to three numbers in a domain, that will give a different (unique) number (in the same domain) for each combination (x,y,z). There will always be some overlap there.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    uint32_t firstInt, secondInt, thirdInt;

    srandom(time(NULL)); /* seed RNG */

    firstInt = random(UINT32_MAX);
    secondInt = random(UINT32_MAX);
    thirdInt = random(UINT32_MAX);

    /* do something with unsigned ints */

    return 0;
}
```

gregor is correct that you will not get a unique value from an algebraic combination of three (or even two) integers. But it's difficult to know what you're really after from the wording of your question. If you really want a unique number, look into a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The question with the title could be interpreted so that this answer is correct. @Downvoter: please explain..

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand.
Venkata has a three numbers collection. Ex: 42, 35, 127. For each combination of these he needs a unique number. Ex:

```
int a[2] = {25, 63, 12};
int b[2] = {149, 28, 56};
GetNumber(a) != GetNumber(b)
```

and GetNumber(a) will always == GetNumber(a), so no random generators.