# Using sizeof in C

Tags: c++, c

I am having the following program, which is crashing. Does anybody know why it is crashing?

```
/* writes a, b, c into dst 
** dst must have enough space for the result 
** assumes all 3 numbers are positive */ 
void concat3(char *dst, int a, int b, int c) { 
    sprintf(dst, "%08x%08x%08x", a, b, c); 
} 

/* usage */ 
int main(void) { 
    printf("The size of int is %d \n", sizeof(int));
    char n3[3 * sizeof(int) + 1]; 
    concat3(n3, 0xDEADFACE, 0xF00BA4, 42); 
    printf("result is 0x%s\n", n3); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Each time you use `sprintf`, I kill a kitten.

Comment: Is this C or C++?  They are not the same language.

Comment: This question is a follow-up to the [Generating unique number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4143473/25324) question by the same poster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're confusing the size of the binary data (which is what `sizeof`) gives you, with the size of a textual representation in hexadecimal, which is what you're trying to store.

On most current systems, `sizeof(int)` evaluates to 4. Your buffer `n3` will therefore be capable of storing 13 characters (3 * 4 + 1 == 13).

Then, you format three integers into 8-character hex format, which will require 3 * 8 + 1 == 25 characters to store. The resulting buffer overflow causes the crash.

It should be obvious that the size of the data type `int` doesn't matter, when you're formatting it as text (and specifying the field width yourself!).

Comment: To hold string "0xDEADFACE", you'd need 11 bytes (10 for the content and 1 for nul character).  That's much larger than the bytes required to hold an integer which for most systems is just 4 bytes.

Comment: change the third line of main to "char n3[25];" and it should work.

Comment: @Venkata: How many digits it takes to write out a number is different from how the number is actually stored inside the computer. sizeof(int) tells you how many bytes it used to store the number inside the computer. How many bytes are needed to store text representing that number is different.

Answer (score 2):

Try `3*2*sizeof(int)+1`, where `2*sizeof(int)` is the number of bytes needed to print each byte worth of an `int`, in hex. Of course since you're using that `%08X` format and expecting fixed-width results, you really should be using `uint32_t`. By the way, your program is also incorrectly passing `0xDEADBEEF` as `int`, which it probably doesn't fit in, and thus entering the realm of implementation-defined conversion-to-signed-type.

Here is a version with those corrections:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* writes a, b, c into dst 
** dst must have enough space for the result 
** assumes all 3 numbers are positive */ 
void concat3(char *dst, uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) { 
    sprintf(dst, "%08"PRIX32"%08"PRIX32"%08"PRIX32, a, b, c); 
} 

/* usage */ 
int main(void) { 
    printf("The size of int is %d \n", sizeof(int));
    char n3[25]; 
    concat3(n3, 0xDEADFACE, 0xF00BA4, 42); 
    printf("result is 0x%s\n", n3); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: For the `sprintf` format string you want `"%08"PRIx32)` rather than `"%08"PRIu32"x"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what `sizeof` has anything to do in your code. In `concat3`, you're attempting to print a text representation of each provided integer as a 8 char hexadecimal string : the required buffer size should thus be equal to 8 * 3 + 1 = 25, and `sizeof(int)` has nothing to do with it.

You seem to be mixing the size occupied in memory by an int, and the length of it's textual representation (which in your case is easily determined as it's fixed by your `sprintf` format string).

On a side note : `sprintf` is a truly unsafe function that you should consider deprecated.

Comment: Cheer up, no one did :) I meant that `sprintf` should probably not be appearing in newly written code and that `snprintf` should be considered. Wouldn't you agree on that point ?

Comment: Basically, yes. But in reality no, not really. `snprintf` does not make string management any simpler as you still have to keep track of string lengths and allocation size. Using `snprintf` does not prevent errors like `char s[2]; /* ... in a subroutine far deep down ... */ snprintf(s, 7, "foobar");`

Answer (score 0):

It is crashing because `sizeof(int)` is (most likely on your system) 4, meaning that `n3` is 13 bytes long.  You then try to write 8 + 8 + 8 = 24 characters to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use snprintf instead of sprintf.  Think of the kittens!

But seriously, you should not be creating interfaces with buffer pointers but no length information.  concat should have a max length parameter.  Then use snprintf inside.  The length to give to concat is sizeof (n3).

It still won't work, but it won't crash either.  The other answers explain how to get the functionality right.

(Oh, and don't use gets() either. Just because it is in the standard library doesn't mean it is good code.)

Comment: Are you confusing `puts` with `gets`? There's nothing wrong with `puts`. It's the most efficient way (in terms of generated code size and probably performance) to print constant lines of text ending in a newline. Modern gcc even replaces `printf` with a constant argument containing no format specifiers and ending in newline with a call to `puts`.